# How not show the web application pages when the user is not logged in and he try to access the pages with just URI in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux, react-router

It's a Basic question I guess for you all, but I just started Web application Development with Reactjs, And right now want to implement this.

When I searched this on the net, the suggestion for implementing ***Protected Routes*** came.
But what is the de-facto standard which we can use in production in order to implement such an Authentication flow?

Scenario:
If the user is not logged in and he directly trys to access one of the pages by directly putting its url on the browser for ex: ***http://localhost:3000/chainpre-ordermonitoring***
he should be redirected to 403 page (Unauthorized Page). and there should be button to take him to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an `HOC` that wraps the your `App` component and contains the user data, inside of that HOC component , you need to check  in `componentDidUpdate`  if user is logged in or (in other words) if you have any user Data in redux or in your state, and if you don't have any, you might redirect user to one of your public routes with `history.push('/somepublicRoute')` like login or something!

Comment: Thanks @a_m_dev for the reply , I am using Redux , So the user Details checking I need to implement for each page individually?

Comment: no, you dont need to implement for each page, you have to implement it once in your HOC and wrap it around your App component, something like `compose(withAuthData)(App)`, because your app component renders all of your routes and inside of your hoc you have access the user data, if there are no user data in your store, it means that the user is not logged in and you need to redirect it where ever you want!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should build an api on the backend which will fo the authentication staff and return a token. As soon as the person hits the forbidden page, you should send a request to backend ang get the token (or in another way). If the token is invalid (this is usully checked on backend), you should return the rollowing: (redirect to login page)

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.loggedIn) return (
        <Redirect to='/login' />
    )

    // otherwise return smth else
```

Comment: Thanks @EgorTrussov for the reply, yes this functionality is present in our backend which is built using flask, but suppose one of the pages is not using backend API's then in that case?

Comment: You can store the token or user info somewhere using redux, contextAPI or local storage, and whenever a person is accessing teh forbidden page you should check if the token or user data which you stored before is valid, and do the redirect stuff next. But I would not recomment doing that, it is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You have two scenarios

=> Accessing a protected route in the front end, for this react router protected routes is a clean way to do it

=> Accessing unauthorized API Call, to properly handle this, I usually create an API Caller method that I use to catch unauthorized errors and route the user to an authorized page from the front-end. Code will depend on your implantation but this is an example for GET using AXIOS

```
import Axios from 'axios';

export const get = (url, params, callback) => {
    Axios
        .get('/api/get/' + url, {
            params: params
        })
        .then((result) => {
            callback(result);
        }).catch((error) => {
            // your error handler routing to your error page
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CharlesdB for the reply, I think we will also need both right?.

1st one for the pages where no call to Backend API is made, and 2nd one for those pages where call ot Backend API is made , to get the data.

If I misunderstood correct me

Comment: You can implement both but I usually only use the second one based on the fact that unauthorized pages will make unauthorized API calls and then redirect anyway... But it might be safer to make both...

Comment: Yeah, But the 1st one is need for the pages where no API calls is made , like homepage or landing page